# acorn throw "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" when parsing Object

Tags: javascript

**acorn version**: 5.2.1

**my code:**

[image]

**The error disappear until like this:**
[image]

It's there any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/205233)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR surround the object with braces `()`, [See it here](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/1b0985b10e33138db5dcf0cbd3c8e8bc/9ae23ab3ec44c9f0d8fcfd4ce28a0689a7542058)

---

This happens because in JavaScript, `{}` not in expression context is parsed to be a block, the `"a":` inside would be a label (if it weren't invalid) and the `{}` would be another, internal block. [See it here](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/fd26bee8e3a8eb9651b50e2ecddb0b82/b75aad1898495eb173a4c07043d78f5d56570712)

By wrapping it in braces, you tell the interpreter that it's actually an expression, and a block can't be in an expression, thus the whole thing must be an object. [See it here](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/1b0985b10e33138db5dcf0cbd3c8e8bc/9ae23ab3ec44c9f0d8fcfd4ce28a0689a7542058)

The reason it works in your second example is that only expressions can be found on the right side of an assignment, which brings it back to expression context.

Comment: This will maybe remove the error, but [acorn](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn) _"is used to parse a JavaScript program"_ and `({"a": {}})` is not a really useful program O.o

Comment: @Andreas My guess is that he's currently messing with it and seeing what's possible or not. What he actually does with it isn't too important.